# Performance test with cProfile > negative function calls

Tags: recursion, performance-testing, function-call, negative-number, cprofile

I´m a beginner with Python, and I just ran a performance test using cProfile. I used a very large graph to test my code. The execution time took more than 2h30 and I got a negative count of function call (-812410634). Why is it negative? And what does it mean?

I appreciate your help.

I expect to get a positive count of function calls.